# How to update PowerBI dataset when new email is received with Power Automate

Tags: powerbi, power-automate, powerbi-datasource, power-automate-desktop, power-automate-custom-connector

how can i make a flow so that when someone send me an email with the updated file attached, the attachment is replaced by the power bi previous dataset.

i had made the flow to save the attachment in sharepoint folder when email with a specific subject is received and it is working,

now how do i make a flow so that when new file is saved in sharepoint folder the new file replaces the current dataset in power bi.

if you have any alternate solutions i am open to that as well

Comment: I suggest you to create a azure function, with http trigger that will upload a new dataset to power bi, and invoke it from power automate. You can use there various languages including power shell...

Answer (score 1):

You can configure Power BI to automatically refresh the Dataset when you update the .pbix in OneDrive or SharePoint.  See [Refresh a dataset stored on OneDrive or SharePoint Online](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/connect-data/refresh-desktop-file-onedrive)